# Azure IAAS SharePoint Farm - Custom domain

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-networking

I have been tasked with figuring out how to setup a SharePoint 2016 farm in AZURE IAAS with VMs. I have a dev farm setup with a virtual network with DC, SQL, Single Farm VM. I have an internal domain name that's demo.mydomain.com that works for the intranet but making it accessible from the internet is the problem. I have public DNS names for each server at servername.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com and I can access my team site from the internet with the "Public DNS Name" of the Single Farm VM.

However, I want to access the SP website from the internet with the internal domain name (that would be the easiest) or with another custom domain name, if that's not possible. The only article I can find is https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10065/associating-a-custom-domain-name-and-securing-communication-with-azure but I don't think this is the right article because it's talking about a cloudapp.net, not cloudapp.azure.com. Also, it just talks about setting up a CNAME or an A RECORD on your domain name providers website to point to the "Public DNS Name" and I need to build this farm out to include Workflow Manager and Office Online server using SSL which is a far more complicated domain scenario.

Does anybody have any idea on how to get information to do this? I'm sure Azure must support it. . .

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two steps involved:

1. Create the necessary entries in your domain server so that users can resolve the address and reach the server. You can either create a CNAME to Azure public name or use the VM IP address and create a Host (A) entry. Second is preferable. Like this:

> myspfarm.mydomain.com (A) "MyAzureVMIPAddress"

2. Once you can resolve the name, then you just need to assign it to a new web application or extend an existing web application to a new zone that uses that name:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276325(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: I am aware of how to extend the web application and adding a CNAME but I'm stuck with the complications of adding an Office Online server which must run on a separate VM and communicate with the Web Front End with a SSL URL. . .

Answer (score 0):

IF you are creating a farm, you are going to need to use an Azure load-balancer to route the requests to the web servers in your farm.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-portal

An over view of the procedure:

1. Create a Azure Public IP
2. Create a network security group (NSG) with rules.
   that allow you to reach your SharePoint farm on the port you have
   opened for SSL traffic on your web servers.
3. Apply the NSG to the public addresses of the web servers in your farm.
4. Create the Azure load-balancer (LB) with the static IP in step 1.
5. Add the backend Pool to the LB consisting of the web servers in your farm or if they are in an availability set - that availability set.
6. Create a LB health probe on the port your are serving the SSL Sharepoint site on
7. Add a load-balancing rule to LB composed of the front end IP from Step 1, backend pool from step 5 and health probe from step 6.
8. Add a DNS a record that points to the CN domain of your SSL cert to the Azure IP.

SharePoint does have it's caveats regarding the SSL certificates and the request URL, and needs to have the SSL certificate loaded through SharePoint central management. That is a different topic than what is being asked here. Alternatively, you can use Application Request Routing (ARR) and use SSL off loading to route to http ports on your SharePoint farm.

Comment: I think Azure load-balancer may help to provide a SSL URL that will work with Office Online communications.  . .need to try it